# Obscure Mathematical Function by Using Trained Machine Learning Model

Tags: regression, machine-learning

Assuming I have mathematical model to describe an IP which could be something like this:
$f_1(x,y) = p_1 \cdot c_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot x + p_3 \cdot y$

The parameters and constants can give some insight of the IP. This can be a problem if the model needs to be exchanged with other people/partners/companies. My question is if it makes sense to use machine learning models to obscure the mathematical function (if a loss in accuracy is acceptable).  Thus, the trained machine learning model can be exchanged instead of the original function $f_1$.

The approach would be a bit different to the classical machine learning approach, since it is no problem to generate any number of training data (by sweeping over x and y) and the whole data-set could be used for training. The same data-set is then also be used for testing and the goal is to get a trained model with the best accuracy on the training set.

Of course some models wouldn't be suitable. A linear regression would give a very similar model and the parameters probably reveal almost the same insight. However, how does it look like for a Ridge regression with RBF kernel, kNN, Decision Tree or MLP? How easy would it be to get some information about the underlying function?

Comment: If the model you exchange with others is accurate, then simpler approximating functions - including the one you have reason to obscure - might be found by using your model to generate data for analysis. The more accurate the model you provide, the more likely such an analysis is to succeed.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. What I intend to do is, to train a machine learning model on the mathematical function. In this way I can exchange the trained model instead of the mathematical function and hopefully avoid revealing any of the internal parameters from the original function. The question would be if you can derive the internal parameters from the internal parameters of the machine learning model.